# How To Fix Segmentation Fault 11 in a C program?

Tags: c, binary, segmentation-fault, hex

I am new to C programming. I'm writing a function that converts an integer into hexadecimal.

For some reason, I am getting a segmentation fault 11. Please advise. Thank you!

Here is the code for my function:

1. it converts the integer to binary first
2. adds 0s where it is needed so binary length would be multiples of 4
3. reverses the order of the binary
4. converts every 4 numbers into hexadecimal

```
void printHexadecimalForm( int X )
//Purpose: Print parameter X in hexadecimal form
//Output: Hexadecimal representation of X directly printed
//Assumption: X is non-negative (i.e. >= 0)
{

    //[TODO] CHANGE this to your solution.

int input = X;
    int output[32];
    int i = 0;
    
    while(input != 0){
        if(input%2 != 0){
            input = input - 1;
            input /= 2;
            output[i] = 1;
            i++;
        }
        else{
            input /= 2;
            output[i] = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }
    while(i % 4 != 0){
       output[i + 1] = 0;
       i++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i/2; j++)
    {
        int temp = output[j];
        output[j] = output[i - 1 - j];
        output[i - 1 - j] = temp;
    }
    int c, k = 0;
    
    for(int z = 0; z < i; z += 4; ){
      
         for (c = z; c < c + 4; c++){
             k = 10 * k + output[c];
         }
         if(k == 0000){
           printf("%d",0);
         }
         if(k == 0001){
           printf("%d",1);
         }
         if(k == 0010){
           printf("%d",2);
         }
         if(k == 0011){
           printf("%d",3);
         }
         if(k == 0100){
           printf("%d",4);
         }
         if(k == 0101){
           printf("%d",5);
         }
         if(k == 0110){
           printf("%d",6);
         }
         if(k == 0111){
           printf("%d",7);
         }
         if(k == 1000){
           printf("%d",8);
         }
         if(k == 1001){
           printf("%d",9);
         }
         if(k == 1010){
           printf("%c", 'A');
         }
         if(k == 1011){
           printf("%c", 'B');
         }
         if(k == 1100){
           printf("%c", 'C');
         }
         if(k == 1101){
           printf("%c", 'D');
         }
         if(k == 1110){
           printf("%c", 'E');
         }
         if(k == 1111){
           printf("%c", 'F');
         }
            
    }

}
```

Comment: When a program doesn't work as expected the thing to do is to debug it. Use a debugger. It will tell you immediately exactly which line of code triggers the seg fault. It will also let you step thru the code and examine state as it runs.

Comment: This does not even compile, so it cannot generate a segfault

Comment: Besides, if you want to print `X` as hex, just do `printf("%x", X)`

Comment: integer literals starting with `0` are octal values, not decimal!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you convert to binary first? And then why bother expanding 4 binary digits to a decimal number?

Comment: `output[i + 1] = 0;` should be `output[i] = 0;`. `c < c + 4` should be `c < z + 4`. The leading zeros on tests such as `k == 0010` should be removed because `0010` is an octal number with decimal value `8`.

Comment: You're mixing octal and decimal constants without realizing it.  `0101` is octal, and has the value 65.  `1000` is decimal, and has the value 1000.

Comment: There's the `c < c + 4` test in a loop. Perhaps you meant `c < z + 4`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take deep breath and start all over again. First remember, there's no need to *convert* anything to binary. Everything *is* binary already.

Maybe this little piece, which retrieves two hexadecimal characters could help you to get on to the track: (this is just one method)

```
int n = 165;         // this is the number we want to display in hex (165 is 0xa5)
int i, hexChar;

i = n & 0xF;          // bitwise AND with 00...001111

if(i < 10)            // look up to ASCII table for more info
    hexChar = i + 48; // character '0' is code 48, '1' is 49 etc.
else
    hexChar = i + 55; // character 'A' is code 65, 'B' is 66 etc.

printf("Rigth most hex: %c\n", hexChar);

i = n >> 4;           // shift all bits 4 steps to the right
i = i & 0xF;          // bitwise AND with 00...001111

if(i < 10)            // look up to ASCII table for more info 
    hexChar = i + 48; // character '0' is code 48, '1' is 49 etc.
else
    hexChar = i + 55; // character 'A' is code 65, 'B' is 66 etc.
    
printf("Second hex: %c\n", hexChar);
```